# MoveIt! Adding Collision Objects

Tags: rviz, moveit, collision, robot, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,
im trying to add some simple collision objects in Python to my planning scene in RViz to plan some trajectories with my UR5 Robot.
I tried something like

```
scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()
p.pose.position.x = 0.4
p.pose.position.y = -0.2
p.pose.position.z = 0.3
scene.add_box("table", p, (0.5, 1.5, 0.6))
```

but this didnt work. Unfortunately the MoveIt! Tutorial is missing this part for Python (only got it for C++). Can anyone help please?

Im running ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255686/moveit!-adding-collision-objects/) by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-27**:
`p.pose.orientation.w` is probably initialised to `0`. That is not a valid quaternion. Try setting `w` to `1` and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you see this related question: #q209030 ? If that doesn't solve your problem: is this the complete code or just a small part? Also, did you see an error message of some sort?

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on 2017-02-28**:
Thanks i found the solution in the related question!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-28**:
So what was the solution in the end?

**Comment by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on 2017-02-28**:
I was missing some parts of the code. Just look at the answer on the linked question, there is the completed code and it worked for me.